# No template found after Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, crud, redirect

Its me again. After two of my questions were solved yesterday, lets try for anotherone. This time I have some problems with the update function of Ruby on Rails.

So, principally the update is doing well. It save the new data and everything is fine, expect one thing: When i click the "save" button, nothing happens on the frontend. As i said, the data is updated correctly, but in my opinion it should me `redirect` to the `root_path` since there is a redirect. May you can tell me what i'm doing wrong? I tried several things with other redirects/render, but nothing worked.

This code is part of my controller:

```
 def update
    @resume = Resume.find(params[:id])
    if @resume.update_attributes(resume_params)
      flash[:success] = 'The file has been updated!'
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

And this is the error I got in the logs:

```
No template found for ResumesController#update, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 96ms (ActiveRecord: 21.1ms)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where's the front end code? The edit page?

Comment: Do you have a `app/views/resumes/edit.html.erb` view?

Comment: You should use `update` instead of `update_attributes`. The latter is just a alias for `update` that is still around for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me and hopefully, it must do for you too if it's saved in DB. Instead of 'Flash' use 'Alert'. I've changed the code according to your code.

```
def update
 @resume = Resume.find(params[:id])
 if @resume.update(profile_params)
   redirect_to root_path, alert: "Your resume is saved!"
 else
   render 'edit', alert: "Oops! There was a problem, please try again"
 end
end
```